# PayPal donation drop-down list

Tags: paypal

How could I have a drop-down list next to my PayPal donation button, where you can select an amount or an "other" option to enter your own amount?

Answer (score 2):

Simply set the name of a select to 'amount', and the value of that select will be posted to PayPal.
Leave it empty (as can be seen with 'Other' in the example below) and PayPal will ask the buyer to enter an amount instead.

```
<form method="POST" action="...................">
<!- Generic PayPal form stuff here -->
<select name="amount">
<option value="1">$1</option>
<option value="2">$2</option>
<option value="3">$3</option>
<option value="">Other</option>
</select>
<!- Generic PayPal form stuff here -->
<!-- Don't forget to set the currency. E.g. USD, EUR, etc.. -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
```